# Cannot insert simple geometry data

Tags: postgis, postgresql, polygon, sql, error

I installed PostgreSQL 9.2.4 and PostGIS 2.0.3 on my Windows 8 machine. Then I created a table using phpPgAdmin and added a geometry column using the following statement.

```
SELECT AddGeometryColumn('tablename', 'area', -1, 'POLYGON', 2);
```

That resulted in these table columns.

```
+------+---------------------+--------+----------------------------------+-----------+
|Column|Type                 |Not Null|Default                           |Constraints|
+------+---------------------+--------+----------------------------------+-----------+
|id    |integer              |NOT NULL|nextval('simple_id_seq'::regclass)|PRIMARY KEY|
|name  |character varying(50)|        |                                  |           |
|area  |geometry(Polygon)    |        |                                  |           |
+------+---------------------+--------+----------------------------------+-----------+
```

After some simple text queries I tried to play with geometry data. This is the query I tried to execute.

```
INSERT INTO tablename (name, area)
VALUES (
    'Lake',
    GeometryFromText('POLYGON((84 104, 212 48, 321 122, 243 179, 275 238, 131 240))', -1)
);
```

Unfortunately, it throws an error message.

```
ERROR:  function geometryfromtext(unknown, integer) does not exist
LINE 4:     GeometryFromText('POLYGON((84 104, 212 48, 321 122, 243 ...
            ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

Since `AddGeometryColumn` was successful, I assume that PostGIS is set up properly. How can I insert geometry data in my table? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use [ST_GeomFromText](http://www.postgis.org/docs/ST_GeomFromText.html).

The functions without the *ST_* are the older functions, and are being phased out; They are [deprecated](http://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/wiki/FAQ#WhenweretheST_functionsfirstaddedtomatchtheSQL-MM-centricconvention), and shouldn't be used any more.

Comment: Thanks, moreover I had to close the polygon, thus add the starting point at the end again.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the value -1 is no longer valid since version 2 of PostGIS.

You can use 0 instead.

Comment: Thanks for the information. Moreover there is an overloaded version of that function with allows you to don't specify the RSID at all.